# Vertical or Horizontal Page Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm looking for a similar implementation of navigation: http://vgtrk.com

I found a similar, but slightly not relevant examples:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/
and 
http://mottie.github.io/visualNav/horiz-vert.html#home

Perhaps there is a similar implementation?
Thanks

Comment: So, what have you tried yourself to implement this? Or are you just looking for a complete plugin to download, not coding anything yourself?

Comment: Tried to run with jQuery. I am looking for an analogue, description, or sample code.

Answer (score 1):

No better way to learn than to dive into pre-existing code & hack away. I think this should cover it:

https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions